# Error: expression must be a modifiable Ivalue

Tags: c++, logical-operators

I wrote this "if" statement in a function with local double-type variables n4_1, n4_2 and n4_3:

`if (n4_1 == 17 && n4_2 == 12 && n4_3 = 2003) { }`

But Windows Studio Intellisense underlines the variables and says:

> Expression must be a modifiable Ivalue
>
> '=' : left operand must be l-value

The values of these variables are assigned through `cin >>` command.

I wanted to run the code inside the "if" statement ONLY if all three condition are true.

Please can you help me and explain me why is this incorrect and how can I correct it?

I'm a beginner so **constructive criticism is welcome**. Thanks in advance and please use simple words lol, I need to understand as clear as possible for the future.

Comment: Looks like `n4_3 = 2003` is a typo and should have been `n4_3 == 2003`, as was done with the other 2 conditions.

Comment: `n4_3 = 2003` would always be true regardless of the value of n4_3 before this statement. However I don't think you want to unconditionally set n4_3 to 2003. Thankfully you got an error here which usually does not happen. Although I would expect a warning.

Comment: "I'm a beginner so constructive criticism is welcome." if you want constructive criticism I would recommend to provide [mcve] in your future questions (this one is quite obvious)

Answer (score 1):

Note that the final part of your `if` is an *assignment*. Note the single `=` in `n4_3 = 2003`.

You can only assign to `n4_3` if it's a modifiable l-value: that is it can appear on the left hand side of `=`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I hadn't noticed it. I tried to run the code right now and it works!